# Нужно разделить строку на слова, убрав знаки препинания

Tags: c++

Я написал, но моя функция не слово в вектор записи делает, а букву.

 Как без помощи стандарта сделать задания?

 Нужна Ваша помощь.

 
Фунция `IsPunctuation` возвращает `bool`, если это пунктуация.


Пример кода:

```
std::vector<char> Split(char* str) 
{
    std::vector<char> ch(strlen(str));

    for (size_t index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; ++index)
    {
        if (IsPunctuation(str[index]))
        {
            ch.push_back(str[index]);
        }
    }
    return ch;
}



UPD:

     bool IsPunctuation(char ch)
    {
        const char* punctuation = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=,./?;:' ";
        for (size_t p = 0; punctuation[p] != '\0'; ++p)
            if (ch == punctuation[p])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

UPD1:
-I
-like
-
-this
-
-it
-
```

Comment: `Как без помощи стандарта сделать задания?` Почему вы тогда используете контейнеры стандарта?

Comment: @ヒミコ я имел введу  без функций стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ведь добавляете в вектор, который хранит `char`, элемент строки, то есть `char`.

Если Вашей целью является получить `vector`, который будет хранить строки,

 полученные из начальной строки, в которой были знаки препинания,

то Вам нужно сперва создать временную строку, в которую Вы будете добавлять

 эти самые "чары", далее добавлять к ней элементы из начальной строки, 

до знака препинания, а уже потом делать `push_back` и добалять это в результирующий `vector`.

На легком примере, если немного изменить Ваш код, и с моей функцией,
 которая просто проверяет на запятую, выглядит это примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool IsPunctuation(char ch)
{
    if (ispunct(ch)|| isspace(ch))
    {
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::string> Split(const char* str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ch;
    std::string tmp;

    for (size_t index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; ++index)
    {
        if (!IsPunctuation(str[index]))
        {
            tmp += str[index];
        }
        else
        {
            if (tmp.length() > 0)
            {
                ch.push_back(tmp);
            }
            tmp.clear();
        }
    }
    ch.push_back(tmp);
    return ch;
}

int main()
{
    const char* TestString = "  hello - - - --,world,test";
    std::vector<std::string> Result = Split(TestString);
    for (auto e : Result)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем. мне нужно знаки пунктуации игнорировать  и их не  записывать в вектор ch

Comment: Например - I, like - football! Мне нужно вывести I like football каждое cлово  с новой строки

Comment: @VovaMakarovych, просто расширяете функцию `IsPunctuation`, которая проверяет не только на запятую, а и другие знаки. А далее из вектора Result выводите строки в консоль с помощью `cout`. Знаки пунктуации я и не записывал в вектор, они пропускались. Суть предложеного мной решения в том, что Вам нужно немного модифицировать его под себя.

Comment: я сделал апдейт и выложил свою функцию IsPunctuation

Comment: @VovaMakarovych, у Вас не получается мой код переписать под свои цели? Что именно Вам непонятно или чего не хватает, чтобы самому дописать код и привести его к нужному результату?

Comment: Да не получается((( Я почему то всеравно  записываю в вектор то что мне не нужно

Comment: @VovaMakarovych, изменил код под Ваши нужны, у меня выводит ожидаемый результат, если что-то получится не так, спрашивайте. И вообще, что именно у Вас не выходит? Что лишнее у Вас записывалось в вектор?

Comment: UPD1 я выложил что у меня выводится. "-" я специально задал чтобы видить. То есть я  записываю в вектор под индексом и есть места где индексы пусты

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100265/discussion-between-lex-marchenko-and-vova-makarovych).